# How to update the textview in a Bluetooh LeScanCallback?

Tags: android, callback, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback to scan for BLE devices. Once I get the required scanned data, I would like to display it on a textview. However, the textview is not updated with the scanned data. Appreciate if anyone could help on this.

```
        private TextView TV_uuid;
        private TextView TV_major;
        private TextView TV_minor;    

    //Find BLE devices
    private Runnable scanRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (isScanning) {
                if (btAdapter != null) {
                    btAdapter.stopLeScan(leScanCallback);
                }
            } else {
                if (btAdapter != null) {
                    btAdapter.startLeScan(leScanCallback);
                }
            }
            isScanning = !isScanning;
            scanHandler.postDelayed(this, scan_interval_ms);
        }
    };


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            TV_uuid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_uuid2);
            TV_major = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_major2);
            TV_minor = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_minor2);  
            //start scan BLE
            scanHandler.post(scanRunnable);     

        }

        private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback leScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice, final int rssi, final byte[] scanData) {
                if (scanData[7] == 0x02 && scanData[8] == 0x15) { // iBeacon indicator
                    UUID uuid = getGuidFromByteArray(Arrays.copyOfRange(scanData, 9, 25));
                    int major = (scanData[25] & 0xff) * 0x100 + (scanData[26] & 0xff);
                    int minor = (scanData[27] & 0xff) * 0x100 + (scanData[28] & 0xff);
                    byte txpw = scanData[29];
                    Log.i(TAG, "iBeacon Major = " + major + " | Minor = " + minor + " TxPw " + (int)txpw + " | UUID = " + uuid.toString()); 
                    TV_uuid.setText(uuid.toString());
                    TV_major.setText(major);
                    TV_minor.setText(minor);
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, that callback runs on a separate thread, so  you shouldn't put view updates in the callback directly.  If you just want to test, you can wrap the view updates inside a runOnUiThread() call and see if that works.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
       public void run(){
         //set the value of your textviews here 
       } 
   }
}
```

Ideally though you should be decouple the scanning from the Activity.  I'd put BLE scanning code inside a service that is  either bound by a client Activity, or sends update to listening clients using LiveData / local broadcast manager.

Comment: thanks for tips. actually i am a newbie in android java. do you have any example on how to implement it?

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: i found a sample code from altbeacon (https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference) which does exactly what i need.

Answer (score 0):

Probably `if (scanData[7] == 0x02 && scanData[8] == 0x15)` is preventing the code to execute. Or you forgot to start the scan and install the onLeScanCallback listener

Comment: the "if" statement works. checked the output in logcat. i already started the scan. i have added the code which does the scanning.

Comment: So, you are saying you see "Log.i(TAG, "iBeacon Major = " + major + " | Minor = "..." in the log? – j3App 17 secs ago   edit